# горячая клавиша для создания скелета в коде

Tags: c++

Не знаю как написать горячую клавишу, чтобы при нажатии определенной кнопки, когда пишешь код, вставлялся цикл, чтобы не прописывать его (тобишь скелет).
(Visual studio 2017)

Comment: visual studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

В Visual Studio для этих целей есть [сниппеты](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2017), для циклов даже встроенные есть `F O R Tab` или `R F O R Tab`например, а также `Ctrl + K-X`